# How to check if 2 directories are on the same partition?

Tags: go, filesystems, system, partition, stat

This code shows a way to check if two directories are on the same partition in linux with python3. Anybody knows how to do the same in Go?

```py
import stat
import os

def same_partition(dir1: str, dir2: str) -> bool:
    stat1 = os.statvfs(dir1)
    stat2 = os.statvfs(dir2)
    return stat1[stat.ST_DEV] == stat2[stat.ST_DEV]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @blami, Why should not I post image or error code, please ?

Comment: Hi, please read the post and accepted answer I linked in my first comment. It explains in detail why pasting source rather than linking image is preferred. TLDR: people can't copy your code and debug it or play with it. Images are often blocked behind proxies in companies, hard to read on mobile or "invisible" for visually impaired people.

Comment: This isn ot a code translation service. You must show your best effort, and explain what problem you're having with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.Stat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat) returns [`os.FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) struct and that provides passthrough via `Sys()` to the underlying data source - on UNIX systems (so the code is obviously not portable to e.g. Windows) it is outcome of `stat` syscall which has device number information. Device number can be obtained from `Dev` field of [`syscall.Stat_t`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Stat_t) struct. Here is a quick example of how to get device number from `FileInfo`:

```golang
// NOTE This is PoC for SO purposes so do error handling, etc.
stat1, _ := os.Stat("/drive1/a.txt")
stat2, _ := os.Stat("/drive2/b.txt")
    
// returns *syscall.Stat_t
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(statA.Sys()))

fmt.Println(stat1.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t).Dev)
fmt.Println(stat2.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t).Dev)
```